# Google Sheet convert to MS Excel app script combined with mail merge

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

I have an existing mail merge tool that is attaching a Google Sheet file in an email but the attachment is converted into PDF. Is there an app script that I can use which will convert the Google Sheet into MS Excel? Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: About `Is there an app script that I can use which will convert the Google Sheet into MS Excel?`, are these threads useful? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D+convert+spreadsheet+to+XLSX